# C#.How can I avoid code repeating when I work with overload

Tags: c#, overloading

Could you tell me how to avoid repeating the code in the case when I should choose overload depending on user input(number of parameters). I'll be greateful for any help.

```
    public int GetSomething(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {

        **var var1= GetSomething(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        var var2= GetSomething(thirdNumber, var1);**

        return var2;
    }

    public int GetSomething(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, int thirdNumber, int fourthNumber)
    {

        **var var1= GetSomething(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        var var2= GetSomething(thirdNumber, var1);
        var var3= GetSomething(fourthNumber, var2);**

        return var3;
    }

    public int GetSomething(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, int thirdNumber, int fourthNumber, int fifthNumber)
    {

        **var var1= GetSomething(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        var var2= GetSomething(thirdNumber, var1;
        var var3= GetSomething(fourthNumber, var2);
        var var4= GetSomething(fifthNumber, var3);**

        return var4;
    }
```

Comment: You code will not compile

Comment: It's just example.

Comment: Does `public int GetSomething(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)` call itself multiple times? You'll probably get an infinite recursion here. Also how does the `thirdNumber` comes to this method?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. All the same, my main question is what to do when the number of parameters is controlled by the user. How to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params).

```
public int GetSomething(params int[] numbers)
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach (int number in numbers)
    {
        total = Calculate(total, number);
    }

    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to avoid duplicating the code by creating a custom extension method for `int` type

```cs
public static class Ext
{
    public static int GetSomething(this int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        //just an example
        return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
}
```

Ans the usage sample

```cs
var firstNumber = 1;
var secondNumber = 2;
var thirdNumber = 3;

var var1 = firstNumber.GetSomething(secondNumber);
var var2 = thirdNumber.GetSomething(var1);

return var2;
```

You can extend this sample to any number of arguments without creating a duplicated methods